# Making ajax list in Javascript

Tags: ajax

I am new to javascript and I am working on an ajax list. I have tried everything to make my delete and edit working, but I am stuck.

my code is here: http://www.mariannelandry.com/testing/test.html

update: It deletes it from the list, but not my database.

Comment: Please start using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) your code would be much more readable and crossbrowser-able.

Comment: I am learning javascript at school. So I have no choice for this right now.